# Сократить выборку из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
$all_brest =array( 'Брест', 'Барановичи', 'Береза', 'Ганцевичи', 'Дрогичин' ,'Жабинка' ,'Иваново', 'Ивацевичи', 'Каменец' ,'Кобрин', 'Лунинец', 'Ляховичи', 'Малорита' ,'Пинск', 'Пружаны', 'Столин', 'Брестская область'); 
$all_vitebsk =array('Витебск','Бешенковичи', 'Браслав', 'Верхнедвинск', 'Глубокое', 'Городок', 'Докшицы', 'Дубровно', 'Лепель', 'Лиозно', 'Миоры', 'Орша', 'Полоцк', 'Поставы', 'Россоны', 'Сенно', 'Толочин', 'Ушачи', 'Чашники', 'Шарковщина', 'Шумилино', 'Витебская область');
$all_gomel =array('Гомель', 'Брагин', 'Буда-Кошелево', 'Ветка', 'Добруш', 'Ельск', 'Житковичи', 'Жлобин', 'Калинковичи', 'Корма', 'Лельчицы', 'Лоев', 'Мозырь', 'Наровля', 'Октябрьский', 'Петриков', 'Речица', 'Рогачев', 'Светлогорск', 'Хойники', 'Чечерск', 'Гомельская область');
$all_grodno =array('Гродно', 'Берестовица', 'Волковыск', 'Вороново', 'Дятлово', 'Зельва', 'Ивье', 'Кореличи', 'Лида', 'Мосты', 'Новогрудок', 'Островец', 'Ошмяны', 'Свислочь', 'Слоним', 'Сморгонь', 'Щучин', 'Гродненская область');
$all_minsk =array('Минск', 'Березино', 'Борисов', 'Вилейка', 'Воложин', 'Дзержинск', 'Жодино', 'Клецк', 'Копыль', 'Крупки', 'Логойск', 'Любань', 'Марьина Горка', 'Молодечно', 'Мядель', 'Несвиж', 'Слуцк', 'Смолевичи', 'Солигорск', 'Старые Дороги', 'Столбцы', 'Узда', 'Червень', 'Минская область');
$all_mogilev =array('Могилев', 'Белыничи', 'Бобруйск', 'Быхов', 'Глуск', 'Горки', 'Дрибин', 'Кировск', 'Климовичи', 'Кличев', 'Костюковичи', 'Краснополье', 'Кричев', 'Круглое', 'Мстиславль', 'Осиповичи', 'Славгород', 'Хотимск', 'Чаусы', 'Чериков', 'Шклов', 'Могилёвская область');




if(isset($_GET["city"])) {
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET["city"]);
    $city = trim ($city);
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Брестская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_brest)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Витебская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_vitebsk)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Гомельская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_gomel)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Гродненская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_grodno)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Минская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_minsk)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Могилёвская область')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('".implode("','",$all_mogilev)."') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сократить выборку в моем случае?Или лучший вид записи?
Может можно эти условия записать в 1 строку и что бы решения выбирались соответственно, как при занесении значений в бд с value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил такой рефакторинг существующего кода

```
<?php
  $cities = array(
    'Брестская область' => array(
       'Брест', 'Барановичи', 'Береза', 'Ганцевичи',
       'Дрогичин' ,'Жабинка' ,'Иваново', 'Ивацевичи',
       'Каменец' ,'Кобрин', 'Лунинец', 'Ляховичи',
       'Малорита' ,'Пинск', 'Пружаны', 'Столин',
       'Брестская область'),
    'Витебская область' => array(
       'Витебск','Бешенковичи', 'Браслав', 'Верхнедвинск',
       'Глубокое', 'Городок', 'Докшицы', 'Дубровно',
       'Лепель', 'Лиозно', 'Миоры', 'Орша', 'Полоцк',
       'Поставы', 'Россоны', 'Сенно', 'Толочин', 'Ушачи',
       'Чашники', 'Шарковщина', 'Шумилино', 'Витебская область'),
    'Гомельская область' => array(
       'Гомель', 'Брагин', 'Буда-Кошелево', 'Ветка',
       'Добруш', 'Ельск', 'Житковичи', 'Жлобин',
       'Калинковичи', 'Корма', 'Лельчицы', 'Лоев',
       'Мозырь', 'Наровля', 'Октябрьский', 'Петриков',
       'Речица', 'Рогачев', 'Светлогорск', 'Хойники',
       'Чечерск', 'Гомельская область'),
    'Гродненская область' => array(
       'Гродно', 'Берестовица', 'Волковыск', 'Вороново',
       'Дятлово', 'Зельва', 'Ивье', 'Кореличи',
       'Лида', 'Мосты', 'Новогрудок', 'Островец',
       'Ошмяны', 'Свислочь', 'Слоним', 'Сморгонь',
       'Щучин', 'Гродненская область'),
    'Минская область' => array(
       'Минск', 'Березино', 'Борисов', 'Вилейка',
       'Воложин', 'Дзержинск', 'Жодино', 'Клецк',
       'Копыль', 'Крупки', 'Логойск', 'Любань',
       'Марьина Горка', 'Молодечно', 'Мядель', 
       'Несвиж', 'Слуцк', 'Смолевичи', 'Солигорск', 
       'Старые Дороги', 'Столбцы', 'Узда',
       'Червень', 'Минская область'),
    'Могилёвская область' => array(
       'Могилев', 'Белыничи', 'Бобруйск', 'Быхов', 
       'Глуск', 'Горки', 'Дрибин', 'Кировск', 'Климовичи',
       'Кличев', 'Костюковичи', 'Краснополье', 'Кричев',
       'Круглое', 'Мстиславль', 'Осиповичи', 'Славгород', 
       'Хотимск', 'Чаусы', 'Чериков', 'Шклов', 'Могилёвская область')
  );

if(isset($_GET["city"])) {
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET["city"]);
    $city = trim ($city);
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь') {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    } elseif(array_key_exists($city, $cities)) {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "')
                  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
                  LIMIT 12";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT *
                  FROM `articles`
                  WHERE city = '$city'
                  ORDER BY `article_id`
                  DESC LIMIT 12";
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю перенести список населенных пунктов из текста скрипта в базу данных, создать следующие таблицы:

Области:

```
create table regions(
  reg_id int not null auto_increment,
  reg_name varchar(200) not null,
  primary key(reg_id)
);
```

Населенные пункты:

```
create table cities(
  city_id int not null auto_increment,
  city_name varchar(200) not null,
  reg_id int null,
  primary key(city_id),
  foreign key (reg_id) 
    references regions(reg_id)
);
```

В таблице articles населенный пункт хранить как его c_id.

После чего выборка всех articles по городу/области будет выглядеть как то так:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM `articles` a, cities c
  LEFT JOIN regions r on r.reg_name=$CITY and c.reg_id=r.reg_id
 WHERE a.city=c.city_id
   and (r.reg_id is not null or c.city_name=$CITY)
```

Можно конечно базу несколько денормализовать, убрав список областей и храня в населенных пунктах название области, вместо id, но я такой подход не могу рекомендовать.

Чем удобна БД - вы можете сделать админскую страничку, которая позволяет менять справочники городов и областей и вам не надо будет менять скрипт при каждом добавлении города и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте таблицу с городами, по типу id, parent_id(или другой древовидной структуры). И добавьте в articles поле city_id

А после меняете весь свой код на выборку по city_id, т.е. вместо

```
if($city == 'Минская область')
```

Будет что-то вроде

```
$city_id = abs( (int) $_GET['city_id'] );
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city_id = $city_id ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
```